# Batch Script to generate multiple command-line instructions

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a batch file `Primary.bat` which collects all the text file names from a particular directory and pipe the output to `Generator.bat`

The contents of `Primary.bat` currently:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Rem Following command will write the names of all files in a text file
dir /b "C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles" > "C:\InputOutput\Generator.bat"
```

So, the contents of `Generator.bat` will be:

```
input1.txt
input2.txt.
input3.txt
unitedstates1.txt
unitedkingdomsales.txt
majorregion100.txt
```

Now I need to add code in `Primary.bat` so that all the above lines gets created in `Generator.bat` with some additional text as per below:

```
converter.java    C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\input1.txt   C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\input1.rtg
converter.java    C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\input2.txt     C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\input2.rtg
converter.java    C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\input3.txt     C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\input3.rtg
converter.java    C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\unitedstates1.txt   C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\unitedstates1.rtg
converter.java    C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\unitedkingdomsales.txt   C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\unitedkingdomsales.rtg
converter.java    C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\majorregion100.txt   C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\majorregion100.rtg
```

Once `Primary.bat` ran you should then just be able to double-click `Generator.bat` which will execute all of the commands.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE!!*** This is assuming that all of the files in the Directory has an `.txt` extension as per your example

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\InputOutput\Generator.bat" move /Y "C:\InputOutput\Generator.bat" "C:\InputOutput\Generator.back"
echo @echo off > "C:\InputOutput\Generator.bat"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%a in ('dir /b C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\') do (
     set result=%%a
     set renamed=!result:.txt=.rtg!
     echo converter.java "C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\!result!" "C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\!renamed!" >> "C:\InputOutput\Generator.bat"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: This is useful , I will  use this suggestion too

Comment: @Aryabhatta The next step would be to see if any answer is useful and select an answer as the correct answer. If they are not able to resolve your issue you are welcome to comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are still some points I don't understand about your code but as far as I understood your task, this should work:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TYPE NUL>Generator.bat
ECHO @ECHO OFF>>Generator.bat
FOR /F %%F IN ('DIR /B InputOutput\SourceFiles') DO (
    ECHO START converter.java "C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\%%F" "C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\%%~nF.rtg">>Generator.bat
)
```

As you only want to execute converter.java, you also can skip `START`. I've suggested `START` to be able to decide how you want to execute your application (eg. by adding `/b` or `/p` or `/w` or whatever as a parameter for `START`).

Comment: This  suggestion is also useful for me to make my script

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Since `converter.java` is a source file, it can't be executed. I therefore assume you mean `java Converter`, which will work assuming you have written a class called Converter, placed it in Converter.java, and compiled it with `javac Converter.java` to create `Converter.class`.

```
@echo off
>C:\InputOutput\Generator.bat (for %%f in (C:\InputOutput\SourceFiles\*.txt) do (
    echo java Converter "%%f" "C:\InputOutput\OutFiles\%%~nf.rtg"
))
```

Comment: This is, I think, the only answer that will cope with spaces in the filenames (should that matter). Also, although the output isn't exactly what the OP _asks_ for (`java Converter` instead of `converter.java`) it's probably what they _want_.

Comment: DodgyCodeException I think i  context was totally different